# How to save and get SharedPreferences in different activities?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've been having issues understanding how to save and read SharedPreferences. I'm trying to save four separate SharedPreferences but as I couldn't figure out how to do it, I decided to try with a simple String.

In this code I'm trying to create and save a string in SharedPreferences

```
        Button enrollNewStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enrollStudentButton) ;

    enrollNewStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.testing), MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.testing), MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("name", "Dave");
            editor.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddNewStudent.class));
        }
    });
```

And in this next part I'm trying to read the SharedPreferences and have a TextView set to it in a second activity.

```
        Context context = this;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.testing),MODE_PRIVATE);
    String toPutInTextView = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.testing), null);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.exampleTextView);
    textView.setText(toPutInTextView);
```

When I run this app and click the button to switch to the second activity the TextView on the second activity is blank.

Does anybody see a problem with this? I've been trying to piece together what I need to do from the android developers website and from other questions here but I just cannot get this working. This is for a university project.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is: `sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.testing), null)` is pulling using the string `getString(R.string.testing)` as the key. However, the key you used when you called `"putString()"` was "name". So you need to use "name" as your key for your `getString()` call.

Try:

```
String toPutInTextView = sharedPref.getString("name", "<default_value>");
```

Comment: Thank you. So if I wanted to use getString(R.string.testing) as the key would I need to change editor.putString("name", "Dave"); to editor.putString(getString(R.string.testing), "Dave");?

Comment: exactly! SharedPreferences work as key/value pairs so you need to use the same key for put and get calls

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that you should probably just use intent.putExtra("name", value) and then getExtras() in your onCreate of your Activity, as there doesn't seem to be any reason to persist the data to sharedPreferences